# TypeError : props.navigation.getParam is not a function. In(props.navigation.getParam('name')

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am facing issue on `TypeError : props.navigation.getParam` is not a function. In `(props.navigation.getParam('name')`. I am using `reactNavigation version 5.x.` this code is working in `reactNavigation 3`. What am I doing wrong?

Here is my code

```
export default class ChatScreen extends Component {
static navigationOption = ({ navigation }) => {
    return {
        title: navigation.getParam('name', null)
    }
}
 
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
   
  
    this.state = {
        person:{
           name:props.navigation.getParam('name'),
            phone:props.navigation.getParam('phone'),
            // name:'Raushan',
          //   phone:9931428888
        },
        textMessage: ''
    };
   
}
```

Error in state section value.
Stack navigator

`

```
const Stack = createStackNavigator();
function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Auth">
        <Stack.Screen name="AuthLoading" component={AuthLoadingScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="App" component={HomeScreen} options={{ title: 'Chats' }}/>
        <Stack.Screen name="Chat" component={ChatScreen} options={({ route }) => ({ title: route.params.name })}/>
        <Stack.Screen name="Auth" component={LoginScreen} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
export default App;
```

`

and Navigate screen

`onPress={()=>this.props.navigation.navigate('Chat',item)}`

Comment: Have you checked the value of `navigation` in your constructor and in your navigationOptions?

Comment: Check react navigation version I think you are using 5.x, they have changed this functionality see this https://reactnavigation.org/docs/params

Comment: React Navigation v5 has a lot of breaking changes if you are coming from v3 or v4.
Read this `Upgrading from 4.x` docs to know more about the changes of library in detail.
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/upgrading-from-4.x/

Answer (score 60, accepted):

**use props.route.params.name** this is working

```
 this.state = {
    person:{
      name: props.route.params.name,
      phone: props.route.params.phone,
    },
    textMessage: ''
};
```

Comment: any reason why to use props.route.params.name instead of  this.props.navigation.getParam("name") ?

Comment: @Swift it's probably because of new version of navigation library

Comment: This works. Also it's wild that everywhere navigation.getParams is being used but it is not valid anymore

Comment: It's wild that react-navigation has so many breaking changes over their major releases. I've been working on this app for over 4 years and when anything breaks because of an update, it's usually react-navigation. Combine that with Apple not supporting older versions of software and you've got a lot of work that nobody asked for.

Answer (score 5):

Mostly you are using the latest version of **React-Navigation** with the same old setup.

So, You gonna pass your custom param as the second argument in the navigation function that I pointed `HERE`:

```js
// Index SCREEN:=>
const IndexScreen = ({ navigation: { navigate } }) => {

  return (
      <View style={Styles.container}>
      <FlatList
        data={state}
        keyExtractor={(item) => `${item.id}`}
        renderItem={({ item }) => (
          <TouchableOpacity
            style={{ ...Styles.singleBlog, ...Styles.rowing }}
            onPress={() => navigate('Previewing', { id: item.id })} // HERE
          >
            <Text style={Styles.blogTitle}>{`${item.title}`}</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        )}
      />
    </View>
  );
};
```

Then you will be able to extract the `id` wirth a new function called `params`
like so:

```js
// PREVIEWING SCREEN:=>
const PreviewScreen = ({ route: { params } }) => {
  const { state } = useContext(Context);

  const { id } = params;
  return (
    <View style={Styles.container}>
      <Text>preview post with id {id}</Text>
    </View>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 3):

As of version `6.x` you need to use `route`.

```
function Index({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <View>
      <Button
        title="Details"
        onPress={() => {
          navigation.navigate('Details', {
            itemId: abcdef
          });
        }}
      />
    </View>
  );
}

function DetailsScreen({ route, navigation }) {
  const { itemId } = route.params;

  // console.log(itemId);
  // abcdef

  return (
    // Content...
  );
}
```

Source: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/params

Answer (score 1):

Yes  I found that in version2, 3, 4 of navigation using getParam.
Link is as follows: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/2.x/params/
when using version5 of navigation using props.navigation.route.param  as per documentation.
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/params/ - version5.

Answer (score 0):

In class component `props` can be access using `this` keyword. So try this :

```js
export default class ChatScreen extends Component {
  static navigationOption = ({ navigation }) => {
    return {
      title: navigation.getParam('name', null)
    }
  }

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      person: {
        name: this.props.navigation.getParam('name'), // access with this.
        phone: this.props.navigation.getParam('phone'), //access with this.
        // name:'Raushan',
        //   phone:9931428888
      },
      textMessage: ''
    };
  }
}
```

Comment: Is this screen is in your stack navigator or outside ?

Comment: Yes. chatscreen is in stacknavigator
 <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Auth">
        <Stack.Screen name="AuthLoading" component={AuthLoadingScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="App" component={HomeScreen} options={{ title: 'Chats' }}/>
        <Stack.Screen name="Chat" component={ChatScreen} options={({ route }) => ({ title: route.params.name })}/>
        <Stack.Screen name="Auth" component={LoginScreen} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>

onPress={()=>this.props.navigation.navigate('Chat',item)}